# Preparing flush failed with VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I get this error when I click start Mavericks on Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager. Do you know how to fix this error?

[image]

```
00:00:29.335737 ********************* End of statistics **********************
00:00:29.335962 VUSB: detached 'HidKeyboard' from port 1
00:00:29.336143 VUSB: detached 'HidMouse' from port 2
00:00:29.349809 AIOMgr: Preparing flush failed with VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED, disabling async flushes
00:00:29.366360 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_cluster, used:0)
00:00:29.367021 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_packet, used:0)
00:00:29.367044 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf, used:0)
00:00:29.367053 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_pagesize, used:0)
00:00:29.367652 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_9k, used:0)
00:00:29.367966 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_16k, used:0)
00:00:29.368123 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_ext_refcnt, used:0)
00:00:29.383296 Changing the VM state from 'DESTROYING' to 'TERMINATED'.
00:00:29.671449 UIMachineView::storeGuestSizeHint: Storing guest size-hint for screen 0 as 720x400
```

**I tried this but does not helped** --> http://maheshbokkisam.blogspot.com/2014/02/aiomgr-preparing-flush-failed-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check whether this issue is applicable to your case  [Mac OS as guest important information](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=31104)

Comment: Hi @psaraj12, I think my problem is other than the information from this website.

Comment: in that case is your maverick Mac OS X Server edition ????.i got the information from the link  https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=63463